# OpenDaylight Live Deployment on Network specs

Tags: sdn, opendaylight

Iam new to Open Daylight  and working on Network Application on Eclipse and using ODL to controll the network , but is there is any specified specs for the  server  that ODL will be deployed , i have read that ODL is deployed as an OVA image on server , but if my server is Ubuntu server do i have to use an ova image , or just intall the ODL on the server ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ODL basic distribution (zip, tar.gz) installs on any machine running java 8. Default installation sets XmX=2G so I would say minimum specs would be 2xCPU + 4GB RAM but that will also depend on your application and how many features you require from ODL.

Comment: sorry another question what is the difference between the application written using maple-fast model [FastMaple](https://github.com/snlab/tutorial-sc16/wiki/Programming-SDN-Networks-using-FastMaple:-A-Tutorial)  and the application written using Eclipse/intellij  Ide and Java